# Get SUM after filtering distinct values

Tags: sql

Hi Guys I need help on getting the sum of a column after filtering the distinct values

Sample table

```
refwo   hrs
123      1
123      1
123      1
456      2
768      2
```

how can i write an sql to get the total "5"?
Ive searhed on this forum and most are saying use "Group by" but i think it will not work since i need 1 value instead of 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **SUM** function to get the Sum of column.

Here is it.

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT hrs) AS Total FROM your_Table_Name GROUP BY refwo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT SUM(Q1.HRS)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT REFWO
  , HRS
  FROM SAMPLE_DATA
  ) Q1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b8c6/20)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT hrs)
FROM
sample_table;
```

your Key is the `DISTINCT` inside `AGGREGATE` function!

If you expected something like this? Go for a view like stuffs!

```
SELECT SUM(hrs)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT hrs , refwo
 FROM
 sample_table) as my_alias;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b8c6/4)

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response, this works well but the problem is i just want to get the total value of "hrs" instead of getting the two columns thats why i think group by will not work.

Comment: for the sample data you posted, can you tell us the expected result?

Comment: i would like just to get the number "5" as result

Comment: for some reason i am having a syntax error on the "select sum(hrs)"                 SELECT sum(hrs)

FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT hrs , refwo
 FROM
sample table])

Comment: What database you use?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Ok got it.. added alias to my subquery.. SQL Server wants it.. it seems!

Comment: it works perfectly! just 1 last question can i still add a where clause on it?

Comment: im trying to add this where clause but it is coming with an syntax error                                                          SELECT sum(hrs)

FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT hrs , refwo 
 FROM
sample_table) as my_alias;
where startdate  between  { ts '2013-12-08 00:00:00.000' } and { ts '2013-12-21 23:59:59.000' }

Comment: can you remove the semicolon after the my_alias ?